# javascript - Adding support for drawing dots in sketch.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have been pulling my hair out for hours trying to find a solution to this.  I have been trying to modify my copy of sketch.js grabbed from [here](http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/) to allow the drawing of dots if the user just taps the button on the mouse and doesn't actually move the mouse while holding it down.  Currently when you try this in sketch.js it just does nothing until you move the mouse.  How could I do this?

Thanks,
Jordan

**EDIT:** I have largely narrowed down this issue and I now assume that somebody in the community will have an answer now.  I have dealt with actually drawing the dots, and that's no issue whatsoever (I just draw an arc on mouseup).  Now the issue is that sketch.js calls this line of code in it's "redraw" function: `this.el.width = this.canvas.width();`.  For whatever reason, this line of code removes the dot I have drawn.  I tried removing this line, but the drawing looks all weird afterwards.

Comment: *Disclaimer:* I don't use SketchJS but I took a quick look at the source so here's some questionable advice. ;-))  Save all your dots as objects in an array. On `redraw`, you must redraw your dots from the saved array. Place your dot redraw code in `tools.draw` because redraw calls tools.draw to redraw the sketch. You will also have to scale the X positions of your dots by the percent change in the canvas width.

Comment: Thanks @markE, I will try that now...

Comment: Works! It really should have been obvious... but whatever